# Android Studio Gradle new "apply plugin"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

All of the tutorials I've read for Gradle explain that the `build.gradle` file should contain either:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

or

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

However, I've just built a new project with Android Studio 0.8.6 and my `build.gradle` now has:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

---

1. Is it purely a syntax change or is there some deeper purpose?
2. What is the new syntax for creating an android library?

Comment: You can find the names of `plugin`s in a `buildscript dependency`: `c:\Users\YourName\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\gradle\0.13.1\629eebffd224396c1a11029424a0495a32f9414\gradle-0.13.1.jar/META-INF/gradle-plugins` (your hashes and version may differ)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. pure syntax change ( I think to avoid collisions / use a 'protected' namespace )
2. com.android.library

this talk from the 2014 gradle summit sheds some more light on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9Fn3ehhU-o from ~ min 15

Comment: There's a deeper purpose in that in the future the fully-qualified plugin name will suffice to find the plugin in a central Gradle plugin repository, eliminating the need for the buildscript/repositories/dependencies/classpath boilerplate required now. This is preparing the ground for that change.

Comment: No, I was looking for a mention of it in the Gradle roadmap and didn't see it. Think of my comment as an idea for the future and not a commitment to a definite feature :)

Comment: The Gradle plugin repository is already [online](http://plugins.gradle.org/). It was announced as part of the [Gradle 2.1-rc-1 release notes](http://www.gradle.org/docs/release-candidate/release-notes).

Comment: yea - but the android plugin is not yet in there